# Why transform : skew(30deg); is not same as transform : matrix(1,0,30,1,0,0);?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Compare the following two code snippets-

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box1 {
  margin: 100px;
  transform: skew(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1"></div>
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box2 {
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 30, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box box2"></div>
```

In the first code snippet I have used `transform: skew(30deg);`
and in the second one I have used   `transform: matrix(1,0,30,1,0,0);`
As you can see in `matrix()` function I have remained all the arguments to their default value except `skewX()` and I change it to `30`. Which should work like `skew(30deg)` according to my assumption. Since the documentation says `matrix()` take arguments like below:

```
matrix( scaleX(), skewY(), skewX(), scaleY(), translateX(), translateY() );
```

IF you run the above code snippets then you found different outputs. Why they are not same? As my assumption says it should be equal because I have used `skewX(30deg)` for both cases.

How the `matrix()` function actually works?

What units are used for `scaleX()`, `skewY()`, `skewX()`, `scaleY()`, `translateX()`, `translateY()` in the matrix function? As `transform: skew(30deg);` and `transform: matrix( skewX(30) );` do not give the same output.

Comment: Maybe this will help you understand a little better, maybe not https://dev.opera.com/articles/understanding-the-css-transforms-matrix/ the transforms matrix does not work like the skew() transform function, it's a lot more mathy.

Comment: @JHeth  I read that document. But I did not found it useful.

Answer (score 5):

The use of matrix is not as easy as you think. We don't add the angle but tangent of the angle:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: skew(30deg);
}

.box2 {
  transform: matrix(1, 0, .577, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
```

You can find more details in the specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#interpolation-of-2d-matrices

You can also inspect the computed value of the element using `skew(30deg)` to see the matrix value:

[image: matrix skew CSS]